# HTML and PHP Contact form with email template

Tags: php, html, email, templates

Here is my code on `contact.php`, the page that generates the email from the website.

I can't find why my html email template is not rendered but only shown as text.

I must be missing something at the `$message_body` side.

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "originsphotography63@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    
    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        
        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'Erreur', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 
        
    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_nom       = filter_var($_POST["user_nom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_prenom    = filter_var($_POST["user_prenom"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_message      = filter_var($_POST["user_message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subject        = "Contact site internet";
    $from           = "www.originsphotography.eu";
    
    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_nom)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Le champ est trop court ou vide'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Veuillez entrer une adresse email valide'));
        die($output);
    }
    
    //email body
    $message_body = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
 <head>
  <title>Nouveau message !</title>
  <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' />
  <style type='text/css'>
   * {
    -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
    -webkit-text-resize:100%;
    text-resize:100%;
   }
   a{
    outline:none;
    color:#40aceb;
    text-decoration:underline;
   }
   a:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}
   .nav a:hover{text-decoration:underline !important;}
   .title a:hover{text-decoration:underline !important;}
   .title-2 a:hover{text-decoration:underline !important;}
   .btn:hover{opacity:0.8;}
   .btn a:hover{text-decoration:none !important;}
   .btn{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition:all 0.3s ease;
    transition:all 0.3s ease;
   }
   table td {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
   .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass a, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass b, .ExternalClass br, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass div{line-height:inherit;}
   @media only screen and (max-width:500px) {
    table[class='flexible']{width:100% !important;}
    table[class='center']{
     float:none !important;
     margin:0 auto !important;
    }
    *[class='hide']{
     display:none !important;
     width:0 !important;
     height:0 !important;
     padding:0 !important;
     font-size:0 !important;
     line-height:0 !important;
    }
    td[class='img-flex'] img{
     width:100% !important;
     height:auto !important;
    }
    td[class='aligncenter']{text-align:center !important;}
    th[class='flex']{
     display:block !important;
     width:100% !important;
    }
    td[class='wrapper']{padding:0 !important;}
    td[class='holder']{padding:30px 15px 20px !important;}
    td[class='nav']{
     padding:20px 0 0 !important;
     text-align:center !important;
    }
    td[class='h-auto']{height:auto !important;}
    td[class='description']{padding:30px 20px !important;}
    td[class='i-120'] img{
     width:120px !important;
     height:auto !important;
    }
    td[class='footer']{padding:5px 20px 20px !important;}
    td[class='footer'] td[class='aligncenter']{
     line-height:25px !important;
     padding:20px 0 0 !important;
    }
    tr[class='table-holder']{
     display:table !important;
     width:100% !important;
    }
    th[class='thead']{display:table-header-group !important; width:100% !important;}
    th[class='tfoot']{display:table-footer-group !important; width:100% !important;}
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body style='margin:0; padding:0;' bgcolor='#eaeced'>
  <table style='min-width:320px;' width='100%' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#eaeced'>
   <!-- fix for gmail -->
   <tr>
    <td class='hide'>
     <table width='600' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='width:600px !important;'>
      <tr>
       <td style='min-width:600px; font-size:0; line-height:0;'>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class='wrapper' style='padding:0 10px;'>
     <!-- module 1 -->
     <table data-module='module-1' data-thumb='thumbnails/01.png' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
       <td data-bgcolor='bg-module' bgcolor='#eaeced'>
        <table class='flexible' width='600' align='center' style='margin:0 auto;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
         <tr>
          <td style='padding:29px 0 30px;'>
           <table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
             <th class='flex' width='113' align='left' style='padding:0;'>
              <table class='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
               <tr>
                <td style='line-height:0;'>
                 <a target='_blank' style='text-decoration:none;' href='https://www.psd2html.com/'><img src='https://www.originsphotography.eu/site/img/image414zdzd4.png' border='0' style='font:bold 12px/12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#606060;' align='left' vspace='0' hspace='0' width='113' height='12' alt='PSD2HTML.COM' /></a>
                </td>
               </tr>
              </table>
             </th>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
     <!-- module 2 -->
     <table data-module='module-2' data-thumb='thumbnails/02.png' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
       <td data-bgcolor='bg-module' bgcolor='#eaeced'>
        <table class='flexible' width='600' align='center' style='margin:0 auto;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
         <tr>
          <td class='img-flex'><img src='https://www.originsphotography.eu/site/img/FAIRY.jpg' style='vertical-align:top;' width='600' height='306' alt='' /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
          <td data-bgcolor='bg-block' class='holder' style='padding:58px 60px 52px;' bgcolor='#f9f9f9'>
           <table width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
             <td data-color='title' data-size='size title' data-min='25' data-max='45' data-link-color='link title color' data-link-style='text-decoration:none; color:#292c34;' class='title' align='center' style='font:35px/38px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; padding:0 0 24px;'>
              Nouveau message !
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td data-color='title' data-size='size title' data-min='25' data-max='45' data-link-color='link title color' data-link-style='text-decoration:none; color:#292c34;' class='title' align='center' style='font:25px/28px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; padding:0 0 24px;'>
              ".$user_prenom." ".$user_nom."
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td data-color='text' data-size='size text' data-min='10' data-max='26' data-link-color='link text color' data-link-style='font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline; color:#40aceb;' align='center' style='font:bold 16px/25px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#888; padding:0 0 23px;'>
              ".$user_message."
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td data-color='title' data-size='size title' data-min='25' data-max='45' data-link-color='link title color' data-link-style='text-decoration:none; color:#292c34;' class='title' align='center' style='font:14px/14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#292c34; padding:0 0 24px;'>
              ".$user_email."
             </td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td height='28'></td></tr>
        </table>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <!-- fix for gmail -->
   <tr>
    <td style='line-height:0;'><div style='display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px/1px courier;'>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</div></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>" ;
    
    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
    
    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Merci, '.$user_prenom .' pour votre message. Je vous réponds très vite !'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting your headers:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust this code below in headers:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer? Or was the goal to get your website in the answer?